# Android drawables sizes not scaling

Tags: java, android, size, drawable

Alright, this seems like it can be a very confusing question but I'm going to try anyway.

I am developing an application right now, and the only thing that you should know is that there are two drawables in this application.

Both drawables have the same exact width. There is a background drawable that obviously goes in the background of the XML. And then theres an ImageView of a simple line. This line is a drawable aswell.

On some devices/emulators, the line is not the full width of its resolution. Despite the fact that both drawables have the same exact width. And both are viewed in the same portrait mode.

Is there any fix to this? Basically this line moves upwards and represents something important, but I can't have it be a different size than the background. I really don't fully understand why the background with a width of 600, and a line with a width of 600 isn't the same size on some devices. Despite putting both drawables in the Drawable folder, and not one for the different resolutions. I currently do not have any screenshots, I will make some if need be, but I hope someone knows why this problem is bugging me and if I am doing something wrong. Can I perhaps tell the application that its resolution must be 800x600, so that all devices that are capable of showing that many pixels, will do so? If this is possible, how do I do this? I hope someone is able to help 
a newbie out :)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/line" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try 9-patch http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Can u show us your xml file?

Comment: Updated with the xml. Just ignore the layout_gravity and centerhorizontal one, I tried something just need to get rid of either one.

Comment: and 9patch didn't work, in the end its still the same size

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scaleType of the imageview to fitXY.

```
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```